# Are there risks to doing ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(tempfile)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

When a file is uploaded, I receive a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, which contains a `tempfile`, that will get cleaned up when the gc cleans it up.

Now I would like to create a job that runs in the background and processes the uploaded file, so that the request can finish quickly. If I kept a reference to the `tempfile` for the background job, it wouldn't get deleted, but only as long as the Ruby process does not restart.

I found that I can do `ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(tempfile)`, and do the deletion myself, at a time of my choosing. Great! I just wonder if there are any risks to undefining the finalizer of a Tempfile?

N.B. An alternative would be to "just" copy the tempfile and work on the copy. But that's wasteful. In my case we are talking up to a few GBs in size total for one upload session.

Comment: You could also just rename the tempfile. For example, add a prefix or suffix to it. That way all tempfiles under your management will have an identifiable tag attached to them, and won't be confused with other tempfiles which might exist in the tmp folder. Renaming is of course a cheap operation if you just keep the files in the same folder, and the Tempfile class won't mind, as it already rescues ENOENT if the file has disappeared when it tries to GC and remove it.

Comment: @Casper Thanks! That's what I'm now doing. (For some reason, although undefine_finalizer seemed to work in irb - however, I did not force a gc - it does not work in the actual rails app)